# How to reverse Bootable USB (closed)

Tags: live-usb, devices

I have a USB that I used to install Ubuntu Mate. But I want to use it again (for college). Any way to reverse this? Inserting my USB does nothing; it won't appear on my devices tab. Any Ideas?

Comment: Formatting it would be a good idea. Use the Disks Utility in Ubuntu Mate for that.